# Jquery .on() and .live() for watermark jquery

Tags: jquery, watermark

How do I change the following so that it is used via jQuery's `.on()` and `.live()`? I'm having a problem converting it so that it binds after an ajax load.

```
$("#name_search").watermark("Search by name...");
```

I'm in the process of changing from jQuery version 1.5 to 1.7, that's why I'm asking about `.on()` and `.live()`. I'm aware `.live()` is deprecated in 1.7.

Thank you

Comment: If that isn't supported by the maker of the plugin, outside of changing the plugin yourself, you'll just have to re-call it.

Comment: Hi James, how do I re-call it? I'm new to jQuery, so still learning

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make `.watermark` work on `$("#name_search")` as soon as it's added to the DOM?  If so, you can't do that just with events (probably).  What you need to do is call `.watermark` when that element is added to the DOM.

```
$("body").append("<div id=name_search>");
$("#name_search").watermark('Search by name...');
```

Comment: Thanks... but how does this work if it the div tag is being added in via a .load()... $("#displayContacts").load($(this).attr("href")); ?

Comment: @AlanHo simply call the `.watermark` in the success function of `.load` (check out the jQuery API).